# What does minus eigenvalue tell us intuitively?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that I solved a eigenvalue problem and I have several positive and negative eigenvalues? Are the eigenvectors correspond to the minus eigenvalues useful?

ADDED:
I have a optimization problem that converted to a generalized eigenvalue problem and the optimal solution are the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues.

Comment: That depends on the (word)problem where the matrix problem comes from, but generally, I would not toss out negative eigenvalues (and their eigenvalues) at all. Can you elaborate a bit on where your eigenvalue problem comes from?

Comment: Thanks, I have added it in the main text.

Comment: The question is too broad to be able to give an answer.

Comment: I tend to agree with copperhat. But generally, if the largest eigenvalue (in abs terms) is to be considered as the pathway to the solution, the entries in its eigenvector give you information about the ratio of the distribution of the quantities in each state (in the long run) The eigenvector to your negative eigenvalue does not have to have negative entries! Check that out first!

Comment: There is no minus value in the eigenvector. What I want to know is what is the difference between positive and negative eigenvalues?